# python elasticsearch format data

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, formatting

I am using the below code to get data from elastic search and i am unable to format it as per my requirement

```
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import json

es = Elasticsearch(hosts=[{'host': "localhost", 'port': "9200"}])

res = es.search(index="myindice",size=2, body={"query": {"match_all":{}}})
for hit in res['hits']['hits']:
  v = hit["_source"]
  q = json.dumps({'name': v['name'],'timestamp': v['@timestamp']})
    print(q)
```

And the output is

```
{"timestamp": "2016-09-22T00:28:44.000Z", "name": "1456772324.47092"}
{"timestamp": "2016-09-22T00:32:16.000Z", "name": "1456772536.57587"}
{"timestamp": "2016-09-22T00:39:19.000Z", "name": "1456772836.57587"}
```

But i want the output like this:

```
{"mydata":[{"timestamp": "2016-09-22T00:28:44.000Z", "name":"1456772324.47092"},
{"timestamp": "2016-09-22T00:32:16.000Z", "name": "1456772536.57587"},
{"timestamp": "2016-09-22T00:39:19.000Z", "name": "1456772836.57587"}]}
```

Could you please help me on how i can achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
mydata = []
for hit in res['hits']['hits']:
    v = hit["_source"]
    mydata.append({'name': v['name'],'timestamp': v['@timestamp']})
result = {"mydata": mydata}
q = json.dumps(result)
print(q)
```